# Google API OAuth access token context. Should I save it globally, per document, or per user?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth

I writing a web application which will handle Google spreadsheets from multiple users (I use Google_Service_Sheets::DRIVE_FILE scope, so each file is requested separately). So, when user grants access to the first file, I save access token given by Google OAuth to my internal stoage to use it for future requests. User should be prompted for access only once when he adds a new file to my app. Currently I testing it on single spreadsheet and it works fine.

But what happens when user adds more spreadsheets to my application? Will each of these files have individual token or it will be the same for all?

And what hapens when another user with different google account provides access to his documents? Will token differ for each of them?

So the question is where I should to store the token - globally, as user property, or as document property?

Answer (score 1):

> I writing a web application which will handle Google spreadsheets from multiple users (I use Google_Service_Sheets::DRIVE_FILE scope, so each file is requested separately). So, when user grants access to the first file, I save access token given by Google OAuth to my internal stoage to use it for future requests. User should be prompted for access only once when he adds a new file to my app. Currently I testing it on single spreadsheet and it works fine.

the access token is only valid for one hour saving it is not needed as its going to expire.

> But what happens when user adds more spreadsheets to my application? Will each of these files have individual token or it will be the same for all?

Each user will have a different access token granting you access to all of the files on their drive account. More sheets wont change that.

> And what happens when another user with different google account provides access to his documents? Will token differ for each of them?

Yes the access token will be different for each user.

> So the question is where I should to store the token - globally, as user property, or as document property?

You shouldn't be saving access tokens, you may want to save refresh tokens but only if you wish to access the users drive account when they are not online. Each token in that case should be saved associated with the user who owns it so that you dont show different users the data of someone else.

Comment: >> First off users are granting you access to ALL the files on their drive account << No, it depends on scope I request with OAuth. I wrote that I use DRIVE_FILE scope, that means "Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app." (from official documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth). BTW, when I re-read this, I found the answer for my question :) Here is the answer: "authorization is granted on a per-user basis". Thank you for the rest of the answer.